# how to set up Autosmush from Github to use

Tags: image, optimization, github, amazon-s3

I have some images inside a bucket that are hosted on Amazon-s3 - http://aws.amazon.com/ and I want to optimise them using Autosmush.I understand the command line to use as shown below

```
./autosmush some-s3-bucket-name/path/to/files
```

but how do I set it up once I've cloned the repo from Github to make it work. This is the repo https://github.com/tylerhall/Autosmush

Answer (score 1):

The [`autosmush`](https://github.com/tylerhall/Autosmush/blob/master/autosmush) file itself has some basic instructions to follow:

```
Autosmush requires the Amazon PHP SDK, which is not included in this project.
// To download and install the SDK, follow these steps...
//
// 1) Download the 1.6.x AWS SDK for PHP from here: https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php/releases
// 2) Unzip file
// 3) Inside the unzipped folder, copy the 'sdk-x.x.x' folder into Autosmush's 'lib' folder
// 4) Rename 'sdk-x.x.x' to 'sdk'
// Enter your credentials
define('AWS_S3_KEY', '');
define('AWS_S3_SECRET', '');
```

That should be enough to start testing the function.

Comment: I wonder where the 'sdk-x.x.x' folder is. https://github.com/tylerhall/Autosmush/issues/15